# How to find the max subset of an array faster than it takes to sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming

I currently have a very large array that I would like to have the top *n* items from, faster than it takes to sort the array. Conceptually I'm pretty sure it's possible to beat whatever sorting algorithm the JS interpreter is using.

Here is the code I'm currently using, which sorts an array of tuples by the second element, and then returns the top 100 tuples. The first item in the tuple is the label, so the desired output is the top 100 items with the highest value.

```
// Sort the array based on the second element
items.sort(function(first, second) {
    return second[1] - first[1];
});

// Create a new array with only the first 100 items
const topItems = items.slice(0, 100);
```

Comment: any sort will need to loop the whole array to find the biggest 100 values, so not that conceptually possible

Comment: It certainly won't be better than O(n), all we're trying to beat is sorting the entire source array.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless the data points are discrete (not floats) and within a known range. If that's the case you could do it in `~O(n)`.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the quickselect algorithm, which has average and best case complexity O(n) with worst case complexity of O(n²).

Getting the top N elements can be achieved by using quickselect to get the N-th element, and since the algorithm also leaves the array halfway sorted, you can just take all the elements over (to the right of) the selected element.

See: [Quickselect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)

Comment: Isn't that what I already proposed? I referenced the "introselect" algorithm, which has better worst-case complexity and the same average complexity of O(n), but it's the same basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

We can definitely beat `O(n log n)` average complexity. For consistent results, since you've declared that we need just the top 100, that is considered a constant (especially since it is small) and using a heap and traversing the array once, we can have `O(n log 100) ≈ O(n * 6.6) = O(n)`. We can be more adventurous and risky by using the introselect algorithm to select the `(N - 100)`th element (where N is the array length) in average `O(n)` time but worst case `O(n log n)`. Then traverse again to select the 100 elements greater than that one.